# Adding a shaded triangle to a ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes, geom-point, triangle

I am actually trying to build a graph showing the fiscal space of a country, so that it looks like [image: this] But for now it looks like
[image: this]

I don't know how to add the transparent triangle like in the model. I tried with several functions but I didn't manage to succeed.

I used:

```
geom_area(x = c(-15, 15, 15), c(-15, -15, 15))

geom_polygon(aes(x = c(-15, 15, 15),y = c(-15, -15, 15), col = 'grey'))
```

as well as

```
triangle <- tibble(x = -15:15)    
geom_ribbon(data = triangle, aes(x, x, ymin=-15, ymax=15), alpha = 0.4)
```

But none of these functions worked. Here is a preview of my code:

```
df %>%
ggplot(aes(CAB, gvtbal, xmin=-15, xmax=15, ymin=-15, ymax=15, colour=year)) + 
  geom_point() + 
geom_label_repel(aes(label= year),
                  box.padding   = 0.35, 
                  point.padding = 0.5,
                  segment.color = 'grey50',
                  max.overlaps = 50,
                  force= 85) +
    # Add lines 45° line for private sector, add x and y axis for CAB and gvtbal
      geom_abline(color='grey') +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color='grey')+
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color='grey')
```

I would like the shaded triangle to cover the area below the `geom_abline` function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `annotate`.

In the absence of a reproducible data I've mocked up a dataset.

I'm assuming you are OK with the labelling of the axis and title as the question is specifically about the shaded triangle.

updated to reflect @KSkoczek's suggestion to place the shaded triangle in an earlier layer so labels are placed on top of the shading.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(CAB = runif(10, 0, 15),
                 gvtbal = runif(10, -3, 1),
                 year = 2001:2010)


df  |> 
  ggplot(aes(CAB, gvtbal, xmin=-15, xmax=15, ymin=-15, ymax=15, colour=year)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  annotate(geom = "polygon", x = c(-Inf, Inf, Inf), y = c(-Inf, Inf, -Inf), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.1 )+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label= year),
                   box.padding   = 0.35, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50',
                   max.overlaps = 50,
                   force= 85) +
  # Add lines 45° line for private sector, add x and y axis for CAB and gvtbal
  geom_abline(color='grey') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color='grey')+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color='grey')+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Great solution, quick add-on: if you want the shaded triangle to not also shade the labels, just move annotate() higher in the list of ggplot parts. It looks neater IMO but will depend on your purposes.

Comment: @KSkoczek really good point, thanks will update the answer.